# Replace specific string in one text file with a incrementing line from another text file

Tags: batch-file, replace, sed, scripting, text-processing

2 files:

in 1.txt

```
a
$test$
b
$test$
c
```

in 2.txt

```
1
2
```

What I want:

```
a
1
b
2
c
```

I prefer `Windows BAT` scripts, but a single Unix executable like `sed` is ok.

UPDATE:

@Magoo's solution works except first character from each line in File 2 is gone :(.

@Aacini's code does not work. Does not copy the entire line from File 1, just the first word. It does copy the entire line from File 2.

Here's the data I used to test this. I'm replacing "URL" in 1.txt with each line in 2.txt:

```
File 1.txt
File Name: 01 - AM FM.flac (FLAC)
File Size: 33.12 MiB (34729455 bytes)
Duration: 00:04:55.173
Audio: FLAC  940 Kbps 44.1 KHz  16 bits 2 channels
asdfsfd URL sdfasdf

File Name: 08 - Chick Habit.flac (FLAC)
File Size: 15.89 MiB (16664220 bytes)
Duration: 00:02:09.093
Audio: FLAC  1 023 Kbps 44.1 KHz  16 bits 2 channels
asfsdf URL asdfsadf
```

File 2.txt

```
[sdfd=http://aaaaaaaa/][IMG]http://aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.jpg[/IMG][/URL]
[sdfdsfd=http://bbbbbbbbbb/][IMG]httbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb.jpg[/IMG][/URL]
```

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried. SO is a portal to ask programming related questions. No one will code everything for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple using [JREPL.BAT - a regular expression text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). JREPL is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

Below is code that will solve your 2nd example (replacing URL)

```
jrepl "URL" "stdin.AtEndOfStream?$0:stdin.ReadLine()" /j /f "file1.txt" <"file2.txt" /o -
```

- `"URL"` The text to search for. You can add regular expression terms to make the search very specifc. As written, it will replace URL even in the middle of a word.
- `"stdin.AtEndOfStream?$0:stdin.ReadLine()"` The replacement expression. If we have reached the end of file2, then it replaces the search with itself, otherwise it replace with the next line in file2.
- `/j` Specifies that the 2nd argument is to be treated as a JScript expression
- `/f "file1.txt"` Specifies the input file that is to be modified
- `<"file2.txt"` Specifies the file from which replacement strings are found
- `/o -` Specifies that the output is to overwrite the original file

Remember that JREPL is itself a batch script, so you must use `call jrepl` if you use the command within another batch script.

Full documentation is available by using `jrepl /?` (or `jrepl /??` if you want paged help)

Comment: I just needed the command, but you went above and beyond the call of duty here. LOL. Happy Holidays.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Read file2 from redirected input
< file2.txt (

   rem Process file1 via FOR /F loop
   for /F %%a in (file1.txt) do (

      rem If line in file1 is "$test$"
      if "%%a" equ "$test$" (
         rem Change it by next line in file2
         set /P "line2="
         echo !line2!
      ) else (
         echo %%a
      )

   )

)
```

Comment: Not working. Does replace the string, but only keeps the first word (before space) in 1.txt.

Comment: @RossKempDeep - That is because your original question implied each input line has exactly one word. You also implied you are always replacing the entire line each time. Aacini's code can be easily fixed to preserve all the words on a line. But replacing a word in the middle of a full line of text will require significant modifications

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, consider this:

`sed -e '/\$test\$/{r file2' -e 'd}' file1`

The logic is not complete as per your requirement, as currently it will paste everything from 1.txt at alternating `$test$` in file 2.txt. So you will have:

```
a
1
2
b
1
2
c
```

**Hint:** Further, you can set up a logic to read only alternating lines from 2.txt. May be a script by looping through 2.txt into a temporary variable and at every loop use the above `sed` command to replace the value from the variable.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what is the purpose of post an "answer" that do NOT solve the question! You may posted this "suggestion" in just a comment instead...

Comment: @Aacini This is because there was no attempt from the OP (or that OP did not post in his question). I was only pointing the OP in a probable direction. I did not have much time to write the script with complete logic and I believe we are here to help. Further, the solution will work if extended correctly. Regarding posting the "suggestion" as a comment, I am afraid I did not have enough reputation then which would allow me to comment on his question. Not something I could have done about it.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "targetstring=$test$"
:: read second file and store contents in $linenumber
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%a IN ('find /n /v "" q34428552_2.txt') DO SET "$%%a=%%b"
SET /a $=0
:: now read-file-and-substitute
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q34428552.txt) DO (
 IF "%%a"=="%targetstring%" (
  SET /a $+=1
  CALL ECHO(%%$!$!%%
  ) ELSE ECHO %%a
)
)>u:\newfile.txt


GOTO :EOF
```

I used files named `q34428552.txt` & `q34428552_2.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces u:\newfile.txt

Essentially, read the substitute-with file into variables names `$1`, `$2` etc.

Then read the main file; if the line does not match the target regurgitate it, but if it matches, substitute the contents of the variable $*count* using `$` as a counter.

Comment: Kinda works. The first character in each line from 2.txt is missing. Specifically the left bracket "[" is not showing up.

Comment: You provided example data. Batch is sensitive to many characters in different situations; that particular construct is sensitive to initial `[` and `]`. You could replace that `find /n /v ""` with `findstr /n /v /r ".*"` and change the `delims` character list to `:` - it would then be sensitive to `:`. Without more information, it's impossible to test every likely scenario.

Comment: Tried to get this to work out of curiosity, couldn't. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/pattern/R file2' -e '//d' file1
```

This replaces each `pattern` from file1 serially with a line from file2.

Comment: This replaces the *entire* line in 1.txt. We want just to replace one string.

Answer (score 0):

using awk (best suite for this need compare to shell script or sed)

```
awk 'FNR==NR{T[NR]=$0;next}/\$test\$/{print T[++i];next}1' 2.txt 1.txt
```

order of file is important

Comment: Just like sed command (via @potong) this replaces the *entire* line in 1.txt